# Ruby on Rails on rendering with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am working on a simple website which has posts in forms of songs, now I have implemented like and dislike feature, but when I click on like/dislike it renders the numbers of likes/dislikes on all posts. And when I reload the page it returns them to normal. Now I would like it to change only the numbers for that particular post, without affecting the numbers on other posts?

My view for posts:

```
<div class="col-6">
    <% for @s in @songs %>
    <div class="card border-secondary mb-1">
        <div class="card-header">
            <div class="col-1">
                <%= image_tag User.find(@s.user_id).user_image.url, :size=>"50x50" %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-11 text-muted">
                <a href="/user/<%= User.find(@s.user_id).username %>" class="info-col">
                    <%= User.find(@s.user_id).username %>                           
                </a> 
                - <%= @s.created_at.to_formatted_s(:short) %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">
            <a href="<%= song_path(@s) %>" class="link-col"><%= @s.title %></a>
        </h4>
        <p class="card-text"><%= simple_format(@s.content) %></p>
        </div>

        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-3" id="song_like">
                        <%= render '/components/song_like' %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-3" id="song_dislike">
                        <%= render '/components/song_dislike' %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-4" id="song_comment">
                        <%= render '/components/song_comment' %>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

The song_like partial has the following code:

```
    <%= link_to like_song_path(@s.id, like: true), remote: true, method: :post do %>
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp <span class="songlikes">
        <%= @s.thumbs_up_total %>
    </span>        
<% end %>
```

The song_dislike partial has the following code:

```
<%= link_to like_song_path(@s.id, like: false), method: :post, remote: true do %>
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp <span class="songdislikes">
        <%= @s.thumbs_down_total %>
    </span>  
<% end %>
```

And my 'like' controller is like:

```
def like
@s = Song.find(params[:id])
@like = Like.create(like: params[:like], user: current_user, song: @s)

respond_to do |format| 
if @like.valid?
    format.html
    format.js
else
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

end

This is how like.js.erb looks like:

```
    $('.songlikes').html("<%=  @s.thumbs_up_total %>");

$('.songdislikes').html("<%=  @s.thumbs_down_total %>");
```

Here is the part of routes.rb file:

```
resources :songs do
  member do
    post 'like'
  end
end
```

I am assuming there is some issue on rendering or jquery, but can't figure it out. Do You have any instructions?

Comment: Okay, there is no new data in your js.

Comment: so how do you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### EDIT: You should remove the `redirect_to` in your f.html?

#### This reloads the page - and the js will therefore not work.

#### An Ajax call is per definition not reloading the page.

If you remove those lines and try the following:

---

There's no new data in your jQuery.

You need a global attribute, so the view can find the data from your controller.

For example:

```
@like = ...
```

Then in your view you can add a local to be rendered:

```
$("#song_like").load("<%=j render partial: '/components/song_like', locals: {like: @like} %>");
```

**But**, you need to change your partial to be a partial. And change the variable to `like` so it will be rendered in the right way.

Hope it helps!

### UPDATE

If you want to hit a specific song you can render it with `each` and then assign an id to your post's class

For example:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <div class="post-content">
    ... other stuff ...
    <div class="likes like-post-<%= post.id %>">
       .. number of likes
    </div> 
    <%= link_to "Like", link_route_path(post) %>
  </div>
<% end %>


# controller 
# So you can use the id in your js view

@id = params[:id]   

# view.js
$(".like-post-" + "<%= @id %>").html("<%=  @s.thumbs_up_total %>");
```

Hope the idea helps.

Comment: Thank You, I will take a look, hope it helps, if it happens to work I'll accept the answer.

Comment: I normally use the `$("#song_like").html(...)` - to change the HTML.

Comment: how do you mean? have You tested it, or You are saying this is the query to use, are You referring to the 'teju c's answer

Comment: I checked my answer this morning and i realised that this was the only line that's different from what i normally use. - so i just wanted to let you know that i haven't myself used load when i've implemented ajax.

Comment: oh, well I did say I do not know jQuery, so I just used load, but yes, if that is the way to go around, I will try that also, anyway, I am still on this issue... Need to check my locals again...

Comment: Okay. And I just saw `<%= j ...`  - the 'j' should be just after like this: `<%=j ..` ---- NOW it should work :)

Comment: I am searching the net, and at some pages I have seen they add 'remote: true' and 'ID' to the link and then they work with that ID, do You think adding an ID could work, because, when I look at the partial with link, that link actually has an icon and number which need to be refreshed? So, perhaps I do not even need to reload/load the div in my view, but rather the link itself

Comment: You already done that in your link: `like_song_path(@s.id, like: true), method: :post, remote: true` - `@s.id` is your id and you're working with that in your controller: `@song = Song.find(params[:id])`

Comment: Can i see your routes.rb to see how the route for the link is set up?

Comment: I don't understand: *when I look at the partial with link, that link actually has an icon and number which need to be refreshed? So, perhaps I do not even need to reload/load the div in my view, but rather the link itself*

Comment: I added the routes.rb part to the question, and ID which I am referring to is: <%= link_to "New Task", new_task_path, id: "new_link", remote: true %> something like this, here they have added an HTML ID to the link and are using it in jQuery, so maybe I need something like that also...

Comment: You are already using the id to find the song and creating the like. It looks fine. But have you changed your `like` to `@like` so the js can find the new variable? Do you have [Byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) or [Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) installed? I would use them to make sure that everything is being created in the controller as it should. For example: is `@like.valid?` 
And can you add your updated `link.js.erb` as well?

Comment: Yes I did change the @like, I will take a look at this all over again during the weekend, then I will come back, hopefully the solution will arise, it is near at least...

Comment: I have managed to get it around and make it t work, apparently I needed to add class to the link instead of the div, but there is still issue. Do You have any advice how to target only one particular post, without affecting numbers on other posts?

Comment: I will try to add this part with ID, Thank You

Comment: Thank You, Your last update with the ID suggestion worked just fine

Comment: If You do not mind, can You please take a look at the question on this link, issue is almost the same, just this time I can't even get it to connect to .js.erb file, here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48735761/render-follow-unfollow-button-in-rails-with-ajax?noredirect=1#comment84473572_48735761 Thank You

Answer (score 0):

change rendering like this:

```
<div class="col-3" id="song_like">
 <%= render partial: '/components/song_like', locals: {s: @s, like: true} %>
</div>
```

then in partial:

```
<%= link_to like_song_path(s.id, like: like), method: :post, remote: true do %>
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp <%= s.thumbs_up_total %>        
<% end %>
```

and in controller of like_song

should define

```
@s= Song.find(params[:id])
like = Like.create(like: params[:like], user: current_user, song: @song)
@like = !like.like # opposite to your current status
```

rest of the things good and then in like.js.erb

```
$('#songs_like').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: '/components/song_like', locals: { s: @s, like: @like } ) %>")
```

Comment: This seems appropriate, I will take a look at it immediately, if it happens to work I will gladly accept the answer as correct. Thank You for detailed info.

Comment: i have one question after like do u want to pass false to like parameter. or opposite to previous like status? if yes i have updated @ like's value in controller

Comment: if you mean will there also be a dislike feature, then yes, it is also implemented, however, I am trying this and few error arised
first was for the 's' saying undefined local variable or method `s', then I added @s and it changed to undefined local variable or method `like', both errors are in partial file, what do You think?

Comment: after completing ajax call? you are getting this issue

Comment: or while coming to page in first place only? anyways updated like.js.erb code check

Comment: well I changed entire code, and hit reload and then error occurred, so before ajax, ok I will try again, I did, well actually the controller is now an issue, I need to fix 'like' value there, as it says undefined variable

Comment: ohh got it change render to render partial in song_like page, when u provide locals it should render partial. updated the same. first render

Comment: Ok with adding render partial it got over the controller issues, ok, I will try to implement everything step by step, and let You know how it went, hope now it will be alright, assuming all other steps are going to work, thank You for everything until now...

Comment: It still does't work, now I am assuming I do not need @s as a local, I will update the view code in the question, please take a look?

Comment: well after ajax complete render partial doesn't get class var, so u need to anyways pass it after ajax complete. So thats why u need to have @s in your partial by sending it as local.

Comment: Ok, will work around it a bit, hope I will get it before returning here...

Comment: I have managed to get it to work but there are still issues with the numbers, do You have any advice for targeting only one post at a time without affecting the others?

Comment: Oh, actually the issue was solved in the previous answer, thank You very much for Your assistance. But if You have some free time, could You take a look at the issues in this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48735761/render-follow-unfollow-button-in-rails-with-ajax  The thing is, i just want to render different form if one is already submitted, I have different kinds of errors, but as I am still learning Rails and do not know or understand much of JS, it is not something I can reach by myself. If You can, please take a look? Thank You.