# render follow/unfollow button in rails with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have implemented follow/unfollow functionality and would like to add AJAX call to it, but I am stuck.
My partial _follow_button.html.erb for follow/unfollow which is rendered on Users->index, looks like:

```
<% if current_user.id != user.id %>    

    <% if !current_user.following?(user) %>
        <%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.build, remote: true) do |f| %>
            <div><%= hidden_field_tag :followed_id, user.id %></div>
            <span class="follow"><%= f.submit "Follow User", class: "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %></span>
        <% end %>
    <% else %>
        <%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: user.id),
                        html: { method: :delete }, remote: true) do |f| %>
            <span class="unfollow"><%= f.submit "Unfollow User", class: "btn btn-secondary btn-sm" %></span>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Then my controller for relationships looks like:

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :js, :json, :html
  def create
        user = User.find(params[:followed_id])
       @follow = current_user.follow(user)
  end

  def destroy
        user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed 
        @unfollow = current_user.unfollow(user)
  end

end
```

My view on user profile looks like:

```
<div class="col-5" style="margin-left: -5px;">
    <%= render '/components/follow_button', :user => User.find_by_username(params[:id]) %>
</div>
```

My routes.rb have the following routes defined:

```
resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end

  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

My Views folder structure has subfolders Users and Relationships. Both of them have separate controllers, and I have tried adding simple alert function 'alert("Works");' to the create.js.erb in both of those subfolders to try and match them with the controller, but none don't seem to work. This is my first Rails project, and I do not quite understand what the issue could be. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you Keith? Almost the same question, less than a day after. Anyway, I posted an answer for Keith and  I think it solves the issue in a better way. Not using forms nor submit. You can easily apply it ti this case. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48732359/3372172

Comment: No I am not Keith... But I will take a look at that answer, although I will then need to edit everything, but hopefully it will work, took a look at it, seems to much, I would still try to fix this issue which I have, as the functionality already works, only render or toggle or something of that kind is an issue, probably the jQuery

Comment: I really think you need just a few changes :)

Comment: I posted an improved (i think) answer based on the one I placed at the other question

Comment: I have checked the functionality behind the posted question, and it seems that the create.js.erb and destroy.js.erb do not even get called, I am assuming there is something which need to be done in my relationships controller or something

Comment: I updated my answer. Your controller should not render any follow.js.erb (or unfollow). Just return to the ajax call with a status (success or not).

Comment: I don't understand `if ..valid?` do this `else` do the same? You use it twice in your controller.

Comment: Well, actually ..valid? seems to be unnecessary as it does nothing it seems, the code worked without it same as it does with it, it is my error, but I do not know do I need to put something else there, oh and yes now that I look at it probably I do not need that else statement, only if ?

Comment: I have removed the else statement from the problem..., but still do not know about valid?, maybe it should be 'save'

Answer (score 0):

**Calling the partial follow/unfollow**

```
<% if current_user.id != user.id %>
  <%= render partial: 'follow_links', locals: { user: user }
<% end %>
```

**Partial follow_links.**

```
<% show_follow_link   = current_user.following?(user) ? 'hidden' : '' %>
<% show_unfollow_link = current_user.following?(user) ? '' : 'hidden' %>

<!-- links to follow/unfollow have data-attributes that include the path to make the ajax post and the user to follow, that is used to find the link to show after the ajax call. You should use the path to the controller that will create or destroy the relationship -->
<%= link_to 'Follow',   '#', { class: 'follow-user btn-success #{show_follow_link}', "data-url": follow_user_path(user.id), "data-followee": user.id } %>
<%= link_to 'Unfollow', '#', { class: 'unfollow-user btn-danger #{show_unfollow_link}', "data-url": unfollow_user_path(user.id), "data-followee": user.id } %>
```

**Javascript for the partial. Ajax post to follow/unfollow**

```
$('.follow-user').on("click",function() {
  follow_unfollow($(this), "follow")
});

$('.unfollow-user').on("click",function() {
  follow_unfollow($(this), "unfollow")
});

function follow_unfollow(target, what_to_do)
  url = target.attr('data-url')
  followee = target.attr('data-followee')
  if (what_to_do == "follow") {
    other_button = $('.unfollow-user[data-followee="'+followee+'"]')
  } else {
    other_button = $('.follow-user[data-followee="'+followee+'"]')
  }

  $.ajax( {
    url: url,
    type: 'post',
    success: function() {
      // Hide this link
      target.addClass('hidden');
      // Show the other link
      other_button.removeClass('hidden');
    },
    error: function(ret) {
      alert(ret.responseJSON.error);
    }
  });

};
```

**Changes in your controller.**

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.find(params[:followed_id])
    @follow = current_user.follow(user)

    respond_to do |format| 
      if @follow.valid?
        format.html
        format.json: { render json: @follow }
        return
      else
        format.html
        format.json: { render json: { :error => 'Follow failed', :status_code :not_found } }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed 
    @unfollow = current_user.unfollow(user)

    respond_to do |format| 
      if @unfollow.valid?
        format.html
        format.json: { render json: @unfollow }
      else
        format.html
        format.json: { render json: { :error => 'Unfollow failed', :status_code :not_found } }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Alright, I will try to implement this functionality

Answer (score 0):

---

#### An advice

An advice, also regarding your last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48284898/ruby-on-rails-on-rendering-with-ajax/48288217?noredirect=1#comment84473948_48288217): I would recommend - instead of posting questions about debugging code on StackOverflow - **create a good debugging environment for yourself**.

[Byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) or [Binding pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) is a good place to start, but before you can use those properly you need to understand the code you are using. I would recommend reading [Working with Javascript](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) in depth! - it really helped me getting the hang of it and understanding the dataflow of Rails and ajax.

This would, i think, break the unbreakable Stackoverflow-loop, that i myself were tied to for a long time:

```
loop do
  puts "Try code"
  sleep 1000
  puts "Arrhh! an error!"
  sleep 1000
  puts "Posting on Stackoverflow"
  sleep 1000
  puts "Waiting for answer"
  sleep 1000
end
```

I hope you figure it out!

Comment: I understand Your advice, but this is my first Rails projects, and I am learning as I go. Naturally, how to work with JS is a must, as it is something I am learning besides Rails at the same time. Well there is a long way ahead of me!